# Why enum can't extend another class while all other classes can

Tags: java, oop, enums

I read from different articles that enum implicitly extends `java.lang.Enum`. That's why enum can't extend another class because multiple inheritance is not allowed in java.

Again each class implicitly extends `java.lang.Object`. But one class can extend any predefined class or user defined class.

1. Why there is difference in behavior?
2. Why a class can extend one class while Object is extended by each class?

Comment: Object is a special snowflake

Comment: I don't understand your question. You already know all enum types are subtypes of `Enum`. If you had a class `A extends B`, then obviously `A` can't also extend some other class. What are you asking?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis : I asking if enum can't extend any other class if `Enum` is extended. Than why a class can extend one class while `Object` is extended by each class?

Comment: * If you do not extend any super class, then that class implicitly extends java.lang.Object class. Else explicitly specified class will be extended. * java.lang.Enum in turn extends java.lang.Object class. But in the case of enum, this is not applicable since java.lang.Enum class is extended implicitly in all the cases.

Comment: It's just language restrictions. It's like you need to either catch or throw upper an exception if it's a sub class of Exception, but not a RuntimeException and subclass of it. Language adds such restrictions to introduce common approach to work with stuff that has specific purpose. In such a case with enums, usually there is no reason to extend enum. In most cases even some logic in enums is not considered good practice.

Comment: You're confusing "extends" and "descends from". It is false that "Object is extended by each class". Since your premise is false, your conclusion that "all other classes can" extend "another" class is false. Like "all other classes" except `Object`, an `enum` can only extend one superclass, and for all `enum`s, that superclass is `Enum<E extends Enum<E>>`.